# Is it possible to check if a future is ready, without consuming its output?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

Futures in Rust can be [polled](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) without blocking to check if the future is ready (and do some work in the process). With that in mind, is it possible to "check" if a future is ready, without [consuming](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/enum.Poll.html#variant.Ready) its output?

#### Possible scenario

`stdin` would be polled if there is any data, and take action on the input ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7a3d041476da9459f273998a616408f)):

```rust
async fn read_input_if_available() {
    use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;

    let mut stdin = tokio::io::stdin();

    // if !stdin.ready() {
    //    return;
    // }

    let mut input = String::new();
    let mut buffer = [0_u8; 1024];

    while let Ok(bytes) = stdin.read(&mut buffer).await {
        if let Ok(string) = std::str::from_utf8(&buffer[..bytes]) {
            input.push_str(string);
        }
    }

    // Take action on `input` here
}
```

When the code hits the `await`, it will not proceed until there is something on stdin, even if just waiting for an `EOF`.

I used `tokio::io::Stdin` because it is simpler for a self-contained example, but the question is about Rust futures in general.

Comment: `stdin` is neither a `Future` nor a `Stream`, so your example code doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

No, not directly. Like iterators, futures and streams are one-shot: you can only get the result of `poll` or `poll_next` once.

Iterators have the [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) method and futures and streams have analogs:

- [`FutureExt::shared`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.shared)
- [`StreamExt::peekable`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.peekable)

In some cases, you may be able to use [`FutureExt::now_or_never`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.now_or_never) combined with the implementation of `Future` for a mutable reference:

```rust
use futures::FutureExt; // 0.3.13
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time; // 1.3.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut f = something_else().boxed();

    if let Some(v) = (&mut f).now_or_never() {
        eprintln!("it was ready and it was {}", v);
    } else {
        time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;

        let v = f.await;
        eprintln!("now it's ready and it was {}", v);
    }
}

async fn something_else() -> i32 {
    //time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    42
}
```

You do need to ensure that the future implements `Unpin` (done here via [`FutureExt::boxed`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed) and you must not `.await` a future after it has already finished.